# I want to show preloader for non ajax call and hide preloader after resources loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am requesting a html5 web page it contains images and sound files. Once all the images and sound files loaded i want to hide a preloader using style property. How do I know last resource loaded for a web page request so that I can hide the preloader?
Note: Here is my situation, I dont use any ajax call it's a normal webpage request.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can wrap your code in `$(window).load` rather than `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I know last resource loaded for a web page request so that I can hide the preloader?

The `load` event fires when all files have finished loading from all resources, including ads and images. This link ( http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html ) from IE9 testdrive demonstrate diffenence between `load` event and `DOMContentLoaded` event (not supported in IE8-).

As result:

1. When page starts to loading you must to register event handler for `load` event and display *preloader message*.
2. When `load` event occur then browser execute your load-event-handler in which you can hide *preloader message*.

Comment: Good example. I modified and used well

Answer (score 0):

Well, you dont really have access to the "loading status" of your image and sound files. But the Browser fires the onLoad-event, if a component is loaded. This works even for images (and mayby soundfiles). see http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_onLoad.html . you can use `$(document).ready(...)` too (for your html-page) if you are using jQuery.